# Injecting instead of instantiating abstract class in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I admit I'm quite new to Spring. I'm working in a Spring Boot application where I'm working with some old code. There are a lot of DAO classes in which the constructor would instantiate an abstract class by overriding the abstract method, like so

```
@Component("exampleDAO_1") // the DAO classes are already managed by Spring
public class ExampleDAO_1 implements IExampleDAO_1 {
...
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME = "property_name_1";
    AbstractClass property;

    public ExampleDAO_1() {
        property = new AbstractClass() {

            @Override
            protected String abstractMethod() {
                return PROPERTY_NAME;
            }

        };
    }
...
}
```

and the abstract class would look something like this

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}") // Ultimately I want the class managed by Spring so I can access this value properly
    private String activeProfile;

    protected AbstractClass() {
        this(true);
    }

    protected AbstractClass(boolean withEnvironment) {
        ...
        // use abstractMethod() here to further set some other fields in the class
        ...
    }

    protected abstract String abstractMethod();

}
```

I want to inject the abstract class instead of instantiating it via the usual `new` keyword and overriding the abstract method, so I can have object Spring managed. What is the best way to go about this?

I've tried making the class concrete to begin with and then passing in the property name into a constructor, then saving the value as a new field in the class, but I'm not sure where to go from there, or if that is even the correct way to start. Apologies if what I'm asking or saying does not make sense.

Comment: Please change your code: `public class AbstractClass` -> `public abstract class AbstractClass`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use Spring in the usual way for abstract classes (i.e. using the `@Component` and the other annotations) because an abstract class cannot be instantiated in Java.

But you can do the following:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME = "property_name_1";

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String activeProfile;

    @Bean
    public AbstractClass abstractClass() {
        return new AbstractClass(activeProfile) {

            @Override
            protected String abstractMethod() {
                return PROPERTY_NAME;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

With this approach, you manually configure `AbstractClass` as a Spring bean. But inside `AbstractClass` you still won't be able to use any Spring annotations, instead you can pass those through the constructor.

And after that, `AbstractClass` can be injected anywhere.

```java
@Component
public class SomeClass {

    @Autowired
    private AbstractClass abstracClass;

    // ...
}
```

I guess the only way to do what you want is above.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for all the DAO classes that were structured as above (except I used `@Autowire Environment env` instead). I'm running into issues with one last class that extends from the abstract class but is a little different.

Specifically, it overrides the abstract method the same as above, but it instantiates itself: `private static final ThisClass INSTANCE = new ThisClass();`. In this class, in order to get the env, I tried a ctor injection and then changed the line as such: `... new ThisClass(env);`. This results in a NPE - instantiation occurs before injection. Any suggestions?

Comment: @p23he, sorry but I don't understand completely your problem. I think it will be great to create another question for your problem. Let me know

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I managed to resolve my problem simply by adding the @Configurable annotation to that particular class. I'm not entirely sure about SO etiquette but I think I'm satisfied with not creating another question. If you're still curious, I'd be glad to share my initial problem and it was solved, however.